# In C++, using operator<< to construct input for a function

Tags: c++, stl, stream, operators, operator-overloading

I would like to be able write code that looks like this:

```
int n;
std::string s = "some string";
SomeFunction("hello world" << n << " " << s << std::endl);
```

Where SomeFunction() is a method of some other class. The point is that I would like to be able to construct input for certain method using operator<<, just the way one'd do when writing to standard output in C++. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: One option that I learned is to define SomeFunction() as macro which creates an instance of SomeClass and then uses operator<<(SomeClass&, std::string&) to write SomeFunction's arguments to SomeClass object. I.e

`std::ostringstream& operator<<(SomeClass&, std::string&);
#define SomeFunction(x) SomeClass() << x`

However, this is not what I want.

Comment: What's wrong with using operator+ and using the '\n' character instead of std::endl (which both appends a `\n` to a stream and flushes it)?

Comment: @sftrabbit: that won't work when `n` is an `int`. @Alexander: is Boost an option?

Comment: If you want that, you'll have to use a stream. But of course, all this is a really periphrastic way to go about constructing a one-off string.

Comment: @larsmans: yes, in general. Do you know how to make it work with boost?

Comment: @Alexander, use Boost.Format: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format/

Answer (score 2):

Your first parameter would have to be a home-made type that overloads `operator<<` and builds some kind of parameter list.

Your class would probably contain an ostream and would forward the `operator<<` to it.

If the function takes a string rather than your mysterious string-building object, you would then need to convert your object back to a string.

You could do it aleady with `ostringstream` like this:

```
int n;
std::string s;
std::ostringstream oss;
SomeFunction( ( oss << "hello world " << n << " " << s << '\n' ).str() );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is way too obvious. I am looking for the code to remain the same as in the sample.

Comment: @Alexander: You can't.  It would require defining `operator<<` for built-in types (`char*` and `int`) which is not allowed.  The closest you could get is `SomeFunction() << arg1 << arg2;`, and only if you control the definition of `SomeFunction`.

Comment: As ildjarn posted below my now-deleted solution (which was almost the same as yours), this won't work because `operator<<` commonly returns `ostream&`, not `ostringstream&`. You'd need to `static_cast` it to get the `str` member.

Comment: I see. Well, I guess I'll have to use a macro.

Comment: @larsmans: Easy to overcome, no `static_cast` needed: `SomeFunction( ((oss << arg1 << arg2), oss).str() );`

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks, but this solution is way too obvious. I am looking for the code to remain the same as in the sample. – Alexander Sandler 54 secs ago

A surprising bias against obvious solutions?

Your syntax just cannot be achieved (in general[1]) without the macro that you describe in the first comment. Period.

[1] In specific cases you might be able to force the issue by overloading to `ostream& operator<<(std::string, myspecifictype)`. In practice this will give you nothing but headaches because just about every use of the << operator will subsequently result in ambiguous overload resolutions

Comment: I didn't ask how to format a string and pass the result to some method. There is number of ways to do it. I wanted the code to look exactly as I've written it. I hoped there's a trick that I missed that would let me do it, but I guess there isn't.

Comment: @Alexander: I appreciate that you do. It might be nicer to your helpers if you mention all that in your question. Just say something like: `I know you can do (A) and your can do (B) but (for reason X) I was really hoping I could keep this exact same syntax, while avoiding the use of a Macro`. It saves us from pointing it all out to you, and also from being 'rejected' for giving 'obvious' solutions(?!), or 'yeah but I don't want that.' - that didn't feel well for me